# Azure DevOps Server on premises build agents are not responding

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops

I've upgraded Azure DevOps Server to latest version (2020 Update 1). After upgradation I'm frequently facing below error, everything looks good on build agent VM and agents itself are up and running.

```
*We stopped hearing from agent Agent1-NightlyBuild-tc3tbld1. Verify the agent machine is running and has a healthy network connection. Anything that terminates an agent process, starves it for CPU, or blocks its network access can cause this error.*
```